# How can I calculate an integral?

Tags: c#, linq

How to build an "integral" function from a Linq expression that returns a series of (time|value) pairs?

E.g. my Linq expression results in a list of (date|quantity) pairs:

```
var quantities = db.Stocks.Find(id).Trades.Select(
    x => new
    {
        date = x.Price.Date.Subtract(unix).TotalMilliseconds,
        value = x.Quantity
    }).ToList();
```

What would be an efficient way to get a series of (date | **cumulated** quantity) where each record has a total of all quantities up to that point, plus the current quantity?

**EDIT1** - to make it concrete: what above query returns could be

- 0: (01.01.2012 | 10)
- 1: (01.01.2013 | -5)
- 2: (01.01.2014 | 7)

What I'm looking for is to have the cumulated value at each discrete point of time:

- 0: (01.01.2012 | 10)
- 1: (01.01.2013 | 5)
- 2: (01.01.2014 | 12)

**EDIT2** - A solution might be to assemble the result 'manually' and to chain each quantity to its predecessor's quantity:

```
var cumulatedQuantities = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
cumulatedQuantities.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(quantities[0].date, quantities[0].value));
for (var i = 1; i <= quantities.Count - 1; i++ )
{
    cumulatedQuantities.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(quantities[i].date, quantities[i].value + cumulatedQuantities[i-1].Item2));
}
```

Somehow, that feels pretty ugly .. but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by date, then total the quantity in each group:

```
var quantities
    = db.Stocks.Find(id).Trades
               .GroupBy(x => x.Price.Date)
               .Select(x => new
                            {
                                date = x.Key.Subtract(unix).TotalMilliseconds,
                                value = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity)
                            })
               .ToList();
```

You could also store it in a dictionary:

```
var quantities
    = db.Stocks.Find(id).Trades
               .GroupBy(x => x.Price.Date)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum(y => y.Quantity));
```

Given your clarification in your question, this will work:

```
var totalQty = 0;
var cumulatedQuantities =
    db.Stocks.Find(id).Trades
      .Select(t => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(t.Id, totalQty += t.Quantity)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think you misunderstood my problem because I did not describe it well enough. In my scenario, each Date will exist only once. Then, GroupBy would not make much sense or would it?

Comment: Regarding your question @peter this is your answer

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much, I would have never come up with something this smooth!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for `Aggregate`

```
db.Stocks.Find(id).Trades
         .Aggregate(new List<Tuple<double,double>>(),
                    (result, next) => {
                                   var total = (result.Any() ? result.Last().Item2 : 0) + next.value;
                                   result.Add(Tuple.Create(next.date, total));
                                   return result;
                               });
```

You may want to vary this a little, like using anonymous objects, a specific class, or a Dictionary to store your results, but this is the basic pattern.

If `Trades` isn't already ordered by date then you should do that too, by adding an `.OrderBy(t => t.date)` before the `Aggregate`